# can the mips pseudo-instruction la be replace by a single MIPS instruction?

Tags: assembly, mips, micro-optimization, instructions

Can the instruction `la  $4,-16($9)` be replaced with a single MIPS machine instruction? I've been searching and every time I find a combination of *lui* and *ori*.

Comment: `la  $4,-16($9)` is just `addiu $4, $9, -16`.  Why are you using `la` in the first place for something that isn't a symbol?  And what assembler is allowing but failing to assemble it to a single instruction?

Comment: For a normal `la` like `la $4, foobar`, a single machine instruction is only possible if the address is in the low 64kiB (`ori`), or is 64k-aligned (`lui`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not using it, I was asked the question and I've been researching.

Comment: What assembler are you using that uses lui + ori?  `clang -target mips foo.s` assembles it to just that `addiu`, according to `llvm-objdump -d` (on my x86-64 Linux desktop).  I assume either MARS or SPIM is dumber for this non-standard use of `la` as a kind of generalized x86-style `lea`, and foolishly waste 2 instructions to materialize `-16` in a register as an input for `addu`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`la` is a pseudo instruction, and, there is one form — `la $<target>, label` — that is effectively essential for MARS and QtSPIM, since these assemblers don't support the %hi and %lo functions that other assemblers support.  You have discovered by searching online that this form of `la` translates into `lui` and `ori` (or something similar).  Because this is probably the most common use of `la`, and an essential form, that's what we find in online search.

However, these assemblers (MARS & QtSPIM) are very helpful in allowing various "nice-to-have" forms that are not actual machine instructions.  So, yes, the form you're showing can be substituted with a single "add" immediate to register operation, which you can (and should) write in the first place.  There's no good reason to use that instead of the more direct `addiu`.  (However, not all forms of `la` can be substituted with one instruction.)

Many pseudo instructions generate more machine code instructions than you would expect.  For example, on MARS, `la $t1, 4($t2)` generates two machine code instructions, one to load constant 4 into `$at` and the other do add reg, reg, `$at` — wholly unnecessary since a single `addiu` would have worked the same.  What's more is that the assembler chooses `add` instead of `addu`, risking a spurious signed integer overflow trap on addressing, which should always be treated as unsigned instead.

---

You can see this for yourself using MARS — just look at the disassembly for a pseudo instruction.